# How to use if condition in Django inside {% block content %}

Tags: python, django

I am trying to apply if condition inside {% block content %} by using the following code:

```
{% for item in execution_log %}

{% if item.description == 'Set On' %}
#Condition

{% elseif item.description == 'Set Off' %}
#Condition

{% elseif item.description == 'FFMPEG error' %}
#Condition

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I am not getting any output. Is the syntax for the if condition correct?

Comment: what does {{ item.description }} displays in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `elif` instead of `elseif`

Comment: The if and elif condition is still not working. I am getting empty results

Comment: Can you do a print of {{item.description}} and check whether you are getting the correct result?

Comment: I printed out the `{{item.description}}` just fine.

Comment: Could you show what it printed? Perhaps there was case sensitive issue.

Comment: You just pointed out my mistake. The 'Set On' was actually 'Set on'. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: before the `{% endif %}`, add these lines and test again. This should drive you to the solution, since you didn't show the code that pushes the `execution_log` in the template context.

```
{% else %}
#UNKNOWN {{ item.description }}
```

Comment: and Install Django Debug Toolbar, that is very useful in such situation (and others).

Comment: The output is from the `{% else %}` part only. The if and elif statement is not working

Comment: So what is the output of the `{% else %}` clause ?
Again, as written above, install the Django debug toolbar in your project https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html then inspect the "Template" panel when on that page. I suspect `execution_log` context variable is NOT what you expect. The issue is in the view function/method that publishes the template. Ah and use `{% elif %}` in place of the unknown `{% elseif %}` of course.

Comment: The `{% else %}` part didnot make any changes. The problem was a typo. Thank you for replying

Comment: And I suspect you have `DEBUG = False` in your project settings, otherwise an explicit template error message would show on your browser.